# $httpBackend e2e not respoding with data

Tags: angularjs, httpbackend

I have a mock server that respond with some data

```js
    backendMock.run(function($httpBackend){
      $httpBackend.whenGET('views/login.html').passThrough();
      $httpBackend.whenGET('views/home.html').passThrough();
      $httpBackend.whenGET('views/quote.html').passThrough();

     var quotes = [{quote:'aint bout how hard you hit'}];

     $httpBackend.whenGET('/quotes').respond(quotes);

    
         
    });
```

to fetch the data from this mock server I am using $http service

```js
 app.controller("quoteCtrl",['$scope','$stateParams','$http',function($scope,$stateParam,$http){
  
    $scope.myquote=$stateParam.id;
    $http.get('/quotes').success(function(data){
      alert(data.quote);
    });
  
  }]);
```

Problem is I am able to hit the server but I am not getting any data back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`quotes` is not defined yet at the time `$httpBackend.whenGET('/quotes').respond(quotes);`is executed. Define it **before**.

Also, your code displays `data.quotes`, but `data` is `[{quote:'aint bout how hard you hit'}];`. So it's not an object, but an array containing a single element, and this element is an object with an attribute named `quote`, not `quotes`.

So the code should rather be

```
alert(data[0].quote);
```

You also shouldn't use `success()`: it's deprecated. Use `then()`:

```
$http.get('/quotes').then(function(response){
    alert(response.data[0].quote);
});
```

Comment: If you want help, you need to be more precise than "not working". What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead, precisely?

Comment: thanks its working fine. i wasn't treating data as array that was the probblrm